# Web site send message

Tags: php, html, email, post, send

When i post a Message from my web page it returns a ? in the browser such as this,

I believe both the HTML and the php to be correct
The html......

```
`enter code here`     
<form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group is-empty">
                    <label for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-     label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group is-empty">
                    <label for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group is-empty">
                    <label for="Message" class="col-md-2 control-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Message">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                  <form action="sendcontact.php" method="post">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                      <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
enter code here
```

Comment: `<form method="POST" action"page_with_php_to_process_the_form.php">` . If you process the form in the same page, the action tag can be empty: `action=""`

Comment: you have not defined action and method to form

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: like form action="actionPage.php" method="POST"

Answer (score 0):

you have declare form method and its action in form tag. Something like as follows

```
<form action="actionPage.php" method="POST"> //you can send data in get method or post method
```

Hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

action="yourLoctionUrl" tell the form where to submit data.
if you will do it empty then it will show ?yourinput fields&other inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="sendcontact.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group is-empty">
                <label for="Name" class="col-md-2 control-     label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group is-empty">
                <label for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group is-empty">
                <label for="Message" class="col-md-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Message">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
              <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You have used form tag twice in your coding. put your `action` and `post` in starting form tag as i did.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the second form tag. Go for this:

```
<form action="sendcontact.php" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
    <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
  </div>
</form>
```